# Finding a computer (Physically) with an IP

Tags: networking

I am trying to figure out which computer may have an IP is there anything that might help me besides the following:

- nmap just shows tcp 3001 open, I have tried throwing some text at that with telnet, but its not responding.
- The MAC address Vendor doesn't help me
- I currently don't have access to the switch
- No ptr / DNS record

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The switch MAC database is the best way to do non-intrusively, but since you say you can't get there, you're going to have to tear things apart.

Start pulling the network apart, piece by piece and, as you do that, attempt to PING the device between changes. Disconnect Ethernet switches until you can make the offending host stop answering. (If it doesn't respond to PING, clear your ARP cache and attempt to PING it. It'll probably answer for ARP even if it doesn't answer for PING.)

Once you narrow it down to a given switch, I'd recommend doing a binary search to pinpoint it as quickly as possible (disconnect half the cables, see if it's there, disconnect half of the half where it was located, repeate until you locate the offending device).

What's the MAC address, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: 00-20-4A-..... PRONET GMBH

Comment: I guess that might help, Desktop / Server NIC?

Comment: Lots of sub-ms pings that could tell me the distance over time? :-P

Comment: So it's probably an embedded device-- SCADA gear, like a PLC or some such. Lantronix owns Pronet Gmbh, so it might have a Lantronix name on it. Could be a Lantronix print server or serial over Ethernet device, too. No such luck re: PING response times... heh heh...

Comment: It is a Lantronix timeclock :-)

Comment: Did you just know that Lantronix owns them, or look that up somewhere?

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that it's probably a Lantronix ETS or SCS serial terminal server, based on its MAC and answering on port 3001.

Comment: Ah, ha... my psychic powers triumph again. I used Gooooogle to search that MAC, came up with Pronet GMBH like you did, then did some searches on Pronet GMBH. I found an SEC filing from Lantronix about the acquisition. From there, I searched "Lantronix TCP port 3001" and found some results that led me to believe that it was a serial-over-Ethernet terminal server device.

Comment: I'm ... impressed :-)

Comment: What happened, anyway? IP conflict? Crazy traffic from the device? (One of my favorite "war stories" relates to, of all things, an embedded time clock device that "went nuts" and ended up intermittently making an AS/400-based line-of-business application fail for a Customer. I was brought in as a "last hope", and told up fron that I wouldn't be paid if I didn't solve the problem, as they'd had several other Firms in who racked up billable labor but didn't solve the problem. I was out the door in 30 minutes w/ the problem solved... heh heh...)

Comment: Damn rep cap... Grrr...

Comment: We were just looking for something else, this was an IP it used to have, and then it was: "what the hell is this?"  It is at a location I don't have physical access to, and the switches are not set up to be managed (even though I think they are managed switches, and I keep saying it would save us time to set that up in the end).

Comment: Total agreement re: setting up switch management before you need it. I feel like a blind man working on networks that have unmanaged switches. I just take for granted being able to find what port a MAC is associated with, etc.

Comment: You deserve a +10 for the use of binary search!